# Как исправить ошибку TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, type-error

```
def check():
    global input, height1, weight, height1, weight1
    
    print("1.Мальчик")
    print("2.Девочка")
    
    input = str(input("Введите Ваш пол по цифре сверху: "))
    
    if input == "1":
      height = str(input("Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): "))
      weight = str(input("Введите Ваш вес: "))
    elif input == "2":
      height1 = str(input("Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): "))
      weight1 = str(input("Введите Ваш вес: "))
    else:
      print("Введите одну из цифр выше!")

check()
```

Перед тем как задать этот вопрос, естественно, я прочитал другие вопросы связанные с этим исключением. У многих ошибка заключалась в лишних, не нужных скобках, а вот у меня - я не знаю.

Я много раз перечитывал свой код в поисках этих лишних скобок, но я их так и не нашёл.

Может ошибка заключается в другом?

Comment: Кст, `input` и так возвращает строку, поэтому оборачивать его в `str(...)` излишне

Comment: ошибку надо приводить полностью, включая строку, в которой она случается, и номер той строки

Comment: Я обернул его в str, потому что уже не знал как выйти из этого положения)

Comment: зачем тут вообще if-elif, если в них одно и то же?

Comment: @Эникейщик видимо, для height, weight и height1, weight1 ;)

Comment: @Jack_oS да это я вижу :) Дальше они наверняка обрабатываются абсолютно одинаково (если вообще обрабатываются), но в разных местах, в зависимости от 1 или 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def check():
    global height, weight, height1, weight1
    
    print("1.Мальчик")
    print("2.Девочка")
    
    sex = input("Введите Ваш пол по цифре сверху: ")
    
    if sex == "1":
        height = int(input("Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): "))
        weight = int(input("Введите Ваш вес: "))
    elif sex == "2":
        height1 = int(input("Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): "))
        weight1 = int(input("Введите Ваш вес: "))
    else:
        print("Введите одну из цифр выше!")

check()
```

`input` уже возвращает строку, преобразуйте ее в `int`, а не в `str`:

```
1.Мальчик
2.Девочка
Введите Ваш пол по цифре сверху: >? 1
Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): >? 23
Введите Ваш вес: >? 21
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Jasur05Mag., если ответ вам помог, вы можете [принять лучший, по вашему мнению, ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) и [проголосовать за все понравившиеся ответы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)

Answer (score 2):

В этой строке вы переписываете имя `input` и теперь в ней будет строка, которую введет пользователь, а не функция [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

```
input = str(input("Введите Ваш пол по цифре сверху: "))
```

Поэтому, при последующем вызове `input`, например в `height = str(input("Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): "))` будет та ошибка

**Решение.** Назовите по другому переменную для `input`

---

**UPD.**

Исправил код из вопроса:

```
def check():
    global sex, height1, weight1, height2, weight2

    print("1.Мальчик")
    print("2.Девочка")

    sex = input("Введите Ваш пол по цифре сверху: ")
    if sex == "1":
        height1 = input("Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): ")
        weight1 = input("Введите Ваш вес: ")

    elif sex == "2":
        height2 = input("Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): ")
        weight2 = input("Введите Ваш вес: ")

    else:
        print("Введите одну из цифр выше!")


sex, height1, weight1, height2, weight2 = ' ' * 5

check()

print(sex, height1, weight1, height2, weight2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, хорошо

Comment: Извините, но поменяв переменную у меня дальше продолжает возникать эта ошибка, str тоже убрал

Comment: @Jasur05Mag., возможно, где-то ошиблись :) Обновил ответ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Заменил переменную `input` на `my_input`, чтобы не было конфликта названий с родной функцией. (А также не конвертирую результат функции `input` в `str`, потому что `input` итак выдает `str`. Хотя это не вызывает ошибок.)

```py
def check():

    global my_input, height1, weight, height1, weight1

    print("1.Мальчик")

    print("2.Девочка")

    my_input = input("Введите Ваш пол по цифре сверху: ")

    if input == "1":

        height = input("Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): ")

        weight = input("Введите Ваш вес: ")

    elif input == "2":

        height1 = input("Введите Ваш рост(в сантиметрах): ")

        weight1 = input("Введите Ваш вес: ")

    else:
        print("Введите одну из цифр выше!")


check()
```